# How to add article code to account invoice in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
class Wtgpurchase(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'produenter code herect.template'     
    code_article = fields.Char(string='code_article')

class WtgFacture2(models.Model):
    _inherit='account.invoice'       
    code_article_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='code article')
    _depends = {     
        'product.template': ['code_article'], }



<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form_inherited55">       
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="partner_id" position="after">         
           <field name="code_article_id.code_article"  />       
        </field></field>
    </record>
```

vue `account.invoice form`
[view_id: 1432, xml_id: wtg24.view_order_form_inherited54, model: account.invoice, parent_id: 539]
None" while parsing /home/khaled/Bureau/eclipse-installer/workspace/wtg_modules/wtg_addons/wtg24/views/wtg_bill.xml:26, near
'

Comment: the error "Le champ `code_article_id.code_article` n'existe pas

Contexte de l'erreur :
Vue `account.invoice form`
[view_id: 1432, xml_id: wtg24.view_order_form_inherited54, model: account.invoice, parent_id: 539]
None" while parsing /home/khaled/Bureau/eclipse-installer/workspace/wtg_modules/wtg_addons/wtg24/views/wtg_bill.xml:26, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form_inherited54">"

Comment: You should really read or re-read the official tutorial of [Building a Module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html). And please try to describe your desired requirement in more detail. Maybe [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good starting point for you.

Comment: thank you sir for your respond , i am new with odoo , what i mean is , after adding a field named 'product code'  to product template , i want to use the same field   on accout invoice and  sale order , 
if possible by choosing the product in the acount invoice , 'product code' will be auto-completed .
thank you sir for help

Comment: You need to use a related field https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-use-related-field-in-odoo-11-135643, and please edit your question and describe your issue.

Comment: @zety thank you sir , it work , but  i want it  to work in both side , when i add and article to the account invoice the code will be added automaticlly,  but i want to add the code in order that the article will be added , could u help me please

Comment: You can override the product `name_search`  method and search for products by `code_article`.